# Accessing ArcGIS Pro geoprocessing history programmatically

Tags: gis, arcgis

I am writing an ArcGIS Pro Add-In and would like to view items in the geoprocessing history programmatically. The goal of this would be to get the list of parameters and tools used, to be able to better understand and recreate a workflow later, and perhaps, in another project where we would not have direct access to the history within ArcGIS Pro.

After a lot of searching through documentation, online posts, and debugging breakpoints in my code, I've found that some of this data does exist privately within the [`HistoryProjectItem`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/sdk/api-reference/#topic11042.html) class, but since this is a private class member, within a sealed class it seems that there would be nothing I can do to access this data. The other place I've seen this data is less than ideal, with the user having an option to write the geoprocessing history to an XML log file that lives within `/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/ArcGISPro/ArcToolbox/History`. Our team has been told that this file may be a problem because certain recursive operations may cause the file to balloon out of control, and after reading online, it seems that most people want this setting disabled to avoid large log files taking up space on their machine. Overall the log file doesn't seem like a great option as we fear it could slow down a user by having the program write large log files while they are working.

I was wondering if this data is stored somewhere that I have missed that could be accessed programmatically from the add-in. It seems to me that the data within [`Project.Items`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/sdk/api-reference/index.html#topic9221.html) is always stored regardless of user settings but appears to be inaccessible this way to due class member visibility. I'm unfamiliar with geodatabases and ArcGIS file formats to know if a project will always have a .gdb which perhaps we could read the history from there.

Any insights on how to better read the Geoprocessing history in a minimally intrusive way to the user would be ideal. Is this data available elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

This was the closest/best solution I have found so far without writing to the history logs that most people avoid due to filesize bloat, and warnings that one operation may run other operations recursively causing the file to balloon massively.

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-sdk-questions/can-you-access-geoprocessing-history-programmatically-using-the/m-p/1007833#M5842

it involves reading the .arpx file (which is written to on save) by unzipping it, parsing the XML, and filtering the contents to only GPHistoryOperations. From there I was able to read all the parameters, environment options, status, and duration of the operation that I was hoping to gain.

```cs
public static void ListHistory()
{
    // this can be run in a console app (or within a Pro add-in)
    CIMGISProject project = GetProject(@"D:\tests\topologies\topotest1.aprx");
    foreach(CIMProjectItem hist in project.ProjectItems
                .Where(itm => itm.ItemType == "GPHistory"))
    {
        Debug.Print($"+++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        Debug.Print($"{hist.Name}");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(hist.PropertiesXML);
        //it sure would be nice if Pro SDK had things like MdProcess class in ArcObjects
        //https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#MdProcess.htm
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        Debug.Print(json);
    }
}
static CIMGISProject GetProject(string aprxPath)
{
    //aprx files are actually zip files
    //https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib
    using (var zipFile = new ZipFile(aprxPath))
    {
        var entry = zipFile.GetEntry("GISProject.xml");
        using (var stream = zipFile.GetInputStream(entry))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
                //deserialize the xml from the aprx file to hydrate a CIMGISProject
                return ArcGIS.Core.CIM.CIMGISProject.FromXml(xml);
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Code provided by [Kirk Kuykendall](https://community.esri.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/201161)